# Find the sum of $\frac {3}{4} + \frac {3}{28} + \frac {3}{70} + \frac {3}{130} .... + \frac {3}{9700}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What will be the sum of :
$\frac {3}{4} + \frac {3}{28} + \frac {3}{70} + \frac {3}{130} .... + \frac {3}{9700}$ ?

Comment: Your terms are of the form ${3\over (3n-2)(3n+1)} = {1\over 3n-2} - {1\over 3n+1}$. This gives you a telescoping series.

Comment: As a first step, you ought to write the sum in $\Sigma$-notation.  In other words, figure out the formula for the $n$-th term.

Comment: @CarlHeckman: $n+3$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\frac {3}{4} + \frac {3}{28} + \frac {3}{70} + \frac {3}{130} .... + \frac {3}{9700}=\frac {4-1}{4} + \frac {7-4}{28} + \frac {10-7}{70} + \frac {13-10}{130} .... + \frac {100-97}{9700}=\left(\frac {4}{4} + \frac {7}{28} + \frac {10}{70} + \frac {13}{130} .... + \frac {100}{9700}\right)-\left( \frac {1}{4} + \frac {4}{28} + \frac {7}{70} + \frac {10}{130} .... + \frac {97}{9700} \right)=1-\frac{1}{100}=\frac{99}{100}$

Comment: Okay, but how did you get the idea of forming this pattern? Are there certain methods one can apply?

Comment: Try to  break the denominator into two factors and check whether difference of any such combination is same as any multiple of the numerator.